# Regex Question: Matching this pattern with hard or soft quotes

Tags: php, regex

I have this anchor locating regex working pretty well:

```
$p = '%<a.*\s+name="(.*)"\s*>(?:.*)</a>%im';
```

It matches `<a` followed by zero or more of anything followed by a space and `name="`

It is grabbing the names even if a class or an id precedes the name in the anchor.

What I would like to add is the ability to match on `name='` with a single quote (') as well since sooner or later someone will have done this.

Obviously I could just add a second regex written for this but it seems inelegant.

Anyone know how to add the single quote and just use one regex?  Any other improvements or recommendations would be very welcome.  I can use all the regex help I can get!

Thanks very much for reading,

```
function findAnchors($html) {
    $names = array();
    $p = '%<a.*\s+name="(.*)"\s*>(?:.*)</a>%im';
    $t = preg_match_all($p, $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    if ($matches) {
        foreach ($matches as $m) {
            $names[] = $m[1];
        }
        return $names;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/<a(?:\s+(?!name)[^"'>]+(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')?)*\s+name=("[^"]*"|'[^']*')\s*>/im
```

Here you just have to strip the surrounding quotes:

```
substr($match[1], 1, -1)
```

But using a real parser like [DOMDocument](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) would be certainly better that this regular expression approach.

Comment: Better use php's built-in DOMDocument + SimpleXML or DOMXPath (it depends...)

Comment: You won't have to strip the quotes manually if you use the branch-reset construct: `(?|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)')`.

Answer (score 2):

James' comment is actually a very popular, but wrong regex used for string matching. It's wrong because it doesn't allow for escaping of the string delimiter. Given that the string delimiter is ' or " the following regex works

```
$regex = '([\'"])(.*?)(.{0,2})(?<![^\\\]\\\)(\1)';
```

\1 is the starting delimeter, \2 is the contents (minus 2 characters) and \3 is the last 2 characters and the ending delimiter. This regex allows for escaping of delimiters as long as the escape character is \ and the escape character hasn't been escaped. IE.,

```
'Valid'
'Valid \' String'
'Invalid ' String'
'Invalid \\' String'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `[]` to match character sets:

```
$p = "%<a.*\s+name=['\"](.*)['\"]\s*>(?:.*)</a>%im";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution won't match anchors with other attributes following 'name' (e.g. `<a name="foo" id="foo">`).

Try:

```
$regex = '%<a\s+\S*\s*name=["']([^"']+)["']%i';
```

This will extract the contents of the 'name' attribute into the back reference `$1`.
The `\s*` will also allow for line breaks between attributes.
You don't need to finish off with the rest of the '`a`' tag as the negated character class `[^"']+` will be lazy.

Comment: Hi pelms,

Thank you for the response.

I gave your regex a try.  Had to escape the single quotes.

$regex = '%<a\s+\S*\s*name=["\']([^"\']+)["\']%i';

I find I am losing the first character of each name string.

Any thoughts?

JG

Comment: Feh, sorry for the munged formatting.

<pre>
$regex = '%<a\s+\S*\s*name=["\']([^"\']+)["\']%i';
</pre>

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

```
$rgx='~<a(?:\s+(?>name()|\w+)=(?|"([^"]*)"|\'([^\']*)\'))+?\1~i';
```

I know this question is old, but when it resurfaced just now I thought up another use for the "empty capturing groups as checkboxes" idiom from the [Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596520694.do).  The first, non-capturing group handles the matching of all "name=value" pairs under the control of a reluctant plus (`+?`).  If the attribute name is literally `name`, the empty group (`()`) matches nothing, then the backreference (`\1`) matches nothing again, breaking out of the loop.  (The backreference succeeds because the group *participated in the match*, even though it didn't consume any characters.)

The attribute value is captured each time in group #2, overwriting whatever was captured on the previous iteration.  (The branch-reset construct (`(?|(...)|(...))` enables us to "re-use" group #2 to capture the value inside the quotes, whichever kind of quotes they were.)  Since the loop quits after the name `name` comes up, the final captured value corresponds to that attribute.

**[See a demo on Ideone](http://ideone.com/O30ef)**